# Извлечение значений из массива в функцию

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть необходимость "развернуть" массив в функцию, или правильнее сказать в конструкцию языка. Собственно код, дабы было понятней:

```
$db = new mysqli('database', 'user', 'password', 'my_db');// подключились
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id`=? OR `id`=?';// запрос с плейсхолдерами
$params = array(1,2);// данные для запроса
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);// отправили запрос на подготовку
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $params);// забиндили данные
$stmt->execute();// выполнили
```

И нам вполне ожидаемо высыпает ошибку

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то распаковать в бинд массив? пробовал:

1. extract()
2. array_chunk($params,1)
3. и пожалуй самое дикое и не поддающееся здравой логике: биндить в цикле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор распаковки массива `...` (для пхп 5.6+)

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii', ...$params);
```